# How to add prefix, suffix & infix to every line with javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a string containing multiple lines like this example:

```
01.jpg
02.jpg
03.jpg
04.jpg
05.jpg
```

I want the final output to be like this:

```
<img data-scr="http://example.com/01.jpg" alt="Page 01.jpg">
<img data-scr="http://example.com/02.jpg" alt="Page 02.jpg">
<img data-scr="http://example.com/03.jpg" alt="Page 03.jpg">
<img data-scr="http://example.com/04.jpg" alt="Page 04.jpg">
<img data-scr="http://example.com/05.jpg" alt="Page 05.jpg">
```

But my javascript isn't outputing what I want. Can anyone help me fix code?

```js
var prefix = '<img data-scr="http://example.com/';
var infix = '" alt="Page ';
var suffix = '">';
var txt = `01.jpg
02.jpg
03.jpg
04.jpg
05.jpg`
var fin = prefix + txt.split('\n').join(infix + '\n' + prefix) + infix + txt + suffix;
console.log(fin)
```

Comment: Why do it this way?  Why not have an array of filenames?  Also, you might consider building actual elements rather than concatenating.  Your script will break if your filenames ever contain reserved characters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of joining immediately, you should *map* each filename to the `<img` string you want and concatenate inside the callback:

```js
var prefix = '<img data-scr="http://example.com/';
var infix = '" alt="Page ';
var suffix = '">';
var txt = `01.jpg
02.jpg
03.jpg
04.jpg
05.jpg`
var fin = txt.split('\n')
  .map(f => prefix + f + infix + f + suffix)
  .join('\n');
console.log(fin)
```

Answer (score 3):

#### Using a `template string`

```js
const txt = `01.jpg
02.jpg
03.jpg
04.jpg
05.jpg`;

const res = txt
  .split("\n")
  .map((t) => `<img data-scr="http://example.com/${t}" alt="Page ${t}">`)
  .join("\n");

console.log(res);
```

Comment: @TravelWhere You're already using template strings in your code, so I assume you know what they are, so why don't you use it again for constructing the image tag, it makes the code look a lot cleaner and readable.